# In C++, how can i declare a variable with a generic type, and instatiate it later?

Tags: c++

I'm developing a university project where i had to implement a Stack class, one using vectors, the other using lists.

Now i'm creating a menu, where you can choose what kind of data do you want inside (int, float, string) and therefore operating on it.

This is what i did:

```
cout<<"You chose to implement a Stack using a vector.\n";
  cout<<"What data do you want in this Stack?\n";
  int data;
  cout << "Press:\n- 1 for int\n- 2 for float\n- 3 for string:\n";
  cin >> data;
  if (data == 1){
    lasd::StackVec<int> stack;
  } else if (data == 2){
    lasd::StackVec<float> stack;
  } else if (data == 3) {
    lasd::StackVec<float> stack;
  }
...
...
```

My idea was to create 3 different stacks, all with the same name, but different instantiation based on your choice. This way, i don't have to create 3 different sub menus, one for int, one for float, and one for string, since every stack i create will be named 'stack'..
Thing is, this way of course my compiler says that the 'stack variable was not declared in this scope'.

So, i thought i could declare it at the start of this menu, but... i don't really know how to do it. I tried a bit but my syntax was always wrong. I wanted to declare it just as a StackVec, without any particular data inside, and then instatiating it later. Any advices? Maybe my plan wasn't optimal and there are many more efficient way i can follow?

Comment: Not sure if you can use it, but `std::variant`? Otherwise you could use a raw `union` and keep track of the choice

Comment: The main issue would be you are mixing two different paradigms, templates are a compile time construct, yet you are trying to defer until runtime. You can work around this by using variants, unions, etc

Comment: Your `stack` objects get out of scope (and destroyed) immediatly after they are created.

Comment: unfortunately, i don't think i can use variant or union. And yes, i know my stack gets destroyed immediately ahahahaha that's what i'm trying to fix

Comment: You'll need to declare the `stack` variable before the scope of the `if`. But what will be its type (has to be determined at compile time) ? One way is to have a common base class for all `lasd::StackVec<T>`s, and then `stack` can be e.g. a `std::unique_ptr<BASE>`.

Comment: @FST It's weird that `union` isn't allowed, but then you could have some sort of templated function that gets called and handles the rest of the code. You can have the stack in that, but that is quite a roundabout way

Comment: Changing templates to inheritance won't help, because you will struggle with parameter/return types. Variant is the only thing that comes to mind, and it would work nicely because of `std::visit`, but I'm aware the learning curve may be steep for this type.

Comment: "This way, i don't have to create 3 different sub menus, one for int, one for float, and one for string" - If you were to proceed with this, I suspect it's likely you'll find other places in your sub menu that need similar dynamic typing. Such as `cin >> foo`  where the type of foo could be `int` or `string` as chosen at runtime. Try writing up the psuedo-code for the rest of what you want and look out for this kind of thing. While it's possible to solve this is complicated ways, it may simpler for your needs to just have multiple sub menus.

Comment: Depends on your need, you could potentially store any of them as `StackVec<string>`, then only parse them into `int` or `float` when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My idea was to create 3 different stacks, all with the same name, but different instantiation based on your choice.

Since you cannot use `std::variant` nor `union`s, as suggested in the comments,
a possible approach is to have a common non-template base type for your
`stack` class. Or, if you don't want to change your hierarchy, you may wrap
your `stack` like this:

```
struct StackWrapper {
    virtual ~StackWrapper() = 0;
};

StackWrapper::~StackWrapper() = default;

template <typename T>
struct ConcreteStackWrapper final : public StackWrapper {
    ~ConcreteStackWrapper() override = default;
    T stack{};  // Put your lasd::StackVec<T> instance here
};
```

Then you have a `std::unique_ptr<StackWrapper>` variable that you downcast
based on the value of `data` (which encodes your data type) when you need to
operate on your stack. The idea is as follows:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct StackWrapper {
    virtual ~StackWrapper() = 0;
};

StackWrapper::~StackWrapper() = default;

template <typename T>
struct ConcreteStackWrapper final : public StackWrapper {
    ~ConcreteStackWrapper() override = default;
    T stack{};  // Put your lasd::StackVec<T> instance here
};

void print_type(int const&) { std::puts("int"); }
void print_type(std::string const&) { std::puts("std::string"); }

template <typename Func>
void execute(StackWrapper& stackWrapper, int i, Func func) {
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            func(static_cast<ConcreteStackWrapper<int>&>(stackWrapper).stack);
            break;

        case 2:
            func(static_cast<ConcreteStackWrapper<std::string>&>(stackWrapper).stack);
            break;

        default:
            assert(false);
            break;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int data = 1; data != 3; ++data) {
    //   ^ This is where you would ask for the data type. I'll just loop.

        std::unique_ptr<StackWrapper> stack{nullptr};
        switch (data) {
            case 1:
                stack.reset(new ConcreteStackWrapper<int>);
                break;

            case 2:
                stack.reset(new ConcreteStackWrapper<std::string>);
                break;

            default:
                assert(false);
                break;
        }

        execute(*stack, data, [](auto const& stack) { print_type(stack); });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
int
std::string
```

I'm not sure how far you can go with this approach. In order to (say) push to
your stack, you have to pass it an `int` or a `std::string` which most probably
you'll have to read from `stdin`.

The only way I can see this working is that you either have a function template
like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void interact_with_user(lasd::StackVec<T>&);
```

that implements your logic in a generic way for `T` in `{ int, float, std::string }`; or you have several functions like these:

```cpp
void interact_with_user(lasd::StackVec<int>&); // int-specific implementation
void interact_with_user(lasd::StackVec<float>&); // float-specific implementation
void interact_with_user(lasd::StackVec<std::string>&); // std::string-specific implementation
```

Then, you may actually implement your program like this:

```
cout<<"You chose to implement a Stack using a vector.\n";
cout<<"What data do you want in this Stack?\n";
int data;
cout << "Press:\n- 1 for int\n- 2 for float\n- 3 for string:\n";
cin >> data;

std::unique_ptr<StackWrapper> stack{nullptr};
switch (data) {
    case 1:
        stack.reset(new ConcreteStackWrapper<int>);
        break;

    case 2:
        stack.reset(new ConcreteStackWrapper<float>);
        break;

    case 3:
        stack.reset(new ConcreteStackWrapper<std::string>);
        break;

    default:
        assert(false);
        break;
}

execute(*stack, data, [](auto const& stack) { interact_with_user(stack); });
```

In either case, you may move the creation of the stack into
`interact_with_user` and have the menu above just call the correct
implementation for the user's choice:

```
void interact_with_user_int(); // this will create its int stack and operate on it
void interact_with_user_float(); // this will create its float stack and operate on it
void interact_with_user_string(); // this will create its std::string stack and operate on it

cout<<"You chose to implement a Stack using a vector.\n";
cout<<"What data do you want in this Stack?\n";
int data;
cout << "Press:\n- 1 for int\n- 2 for float\n- 3 for string:\n";
cin >> data;

std::unique_ptr<StackWrapper> stack{nullptr};
switch (data) {
    case 1:
        interact_with_user_int();
        break;

    case 2:
        interact_with_user_float();
        break;

    case 3:
        interact_with_user_string();
        break;

    default:
        assert(false);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, you really helped me a lot.